# Invisible Object Show Up In Final Render

Tags: cycles-render-engine, rendering

I am using Blender 2.79 I have an object that appears in the Cycles render that is not in the original scene. I have closed the file down and reloaded it. I checked everything in the outliner window looking for something. I am sure the object is a straggler as it was something I created before. I checked all the eye icons and they are all turned on. I tried to box select to see if I could snag the hidden item but nothing is selected.

If I use the render in the display viewports mode the invisible object does not show up. It only appears in the main render window. Any help with this would be appreciated. Thanks

Comment: Do you have any other of this kind of object in your scene? Is it possible that it is a reflection of another object. A screenshot would be very helpful as well, as I can only guess otherwise.

Comment: Is it on a separate layer? Have you checked the object properties/cycles settings/shading options? Include your blender file so one can take a looks...

Comment: what this question have to share with the title "import objects change scale"?

Comment: Thanks for your comments, The object that shows up in the render is not like anything in the scene and I only have one layer active for this scene.  But that was a great suggestion. I have selected almost ever other object and moved them around to see if the object was attached from  when I Appended objects into the scene but so far no luck. I gave up last night but will move some more objects around latter today. It has to be associated with something. Very strange.

Answer (score 1):

I finally figured this problem out. I keep moving objects around then would render to see if the invisible object would move with it. After about a half hour of moving objects around I found the one object that was attached to the invisible object. It must have come in when I appended an object to the scene.  This invisible object was attached to many objects joined together. Which one is the culprit attached to the invisible one is beyond me.  It would be very time consuming to separate them all so just deleted. This fixed the problem.  But this still does not explain why the object came in invisible when it was appended into the scene.